# Getting all the map theme names and associated layers and styles names in a QGIS project with python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

We are using map themes in combination with layer styles in a QGIS project to get the layer visibility and symbology we need for a growing number of layouts.

We want to keep track of the existing themes and the layers and layer styles in use, so we are using QGIS python console to get this information.

So far we managed to  print the map themes and the visible layers for each of them in the current QGIS project and we have a different python code to get all the styles for each layer in the project as a reference (so we can identify the unused styles).

Our problem is that we can't find a way of also printing the style applied to each layer referenced in each theme.

This code block prints all the layer names and all the style names defined for each.

```
mapGeometryType = {
    0: "Point",
    1: "Line",
    2: "Polygon",
    3: "UnknownGeometry",
    4: "NullGeometry",
}
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
for layer in layers.values():
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        if mapGeometryType[layer.geometryType()] != "NullGeometry":
            stlmngr = layer.styleManager()
            styles = stlmngr.styles()
            for style in styles:
                print (str(layer.name()) + ';' + str(style))
```

This code prints all the theme names and the visible layer names for each. We'd like to also show the style used for every visible layers in each theme.

```
project = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance()
coll = project.mapThemeCollection()
preset_names = coll.mapThemes()
for name in preset_names:
    theme_layers = coll.mapThemeVisibleLayers(name)
    for layer in theme_layers:
        print (str(name) + ':' + str(layer))
```

At first we tried to sort of combine both code blocks which was not the way to go so we looked for something else.
There's this layerStyleOverrides(theme) method from the QgsMapThemeCollection class (see [here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsMapThemeCollection.html#qgis.core.QgsMapThemeCollection.mapThemeStyleOverrides)) but we are unable of using it properly. The QGis project hangs at every attempt.

This is what we have now. It's not printing the style names and it hangs really quickly.

```
project = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance()
coll = project.mapThemeCollection()
preset_names = coll.mapThemes()
for name in preset_names:
    stls = coll.mapThemeStyleOverrides(name)
    for stl in stls:
        print (str(name) + ';' + str(stl))
```